# Vue Does not change array data from expansion panel and activate loader

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

i have problem with vue. when i click get deposit address i activate function:

```
getAddress(i){
 loader[i] = true;
 ...some other operations
}
```

this is how it should look: I click the "get address" button, it activates the function and sets the "loader[i]" to true, then vuetify will show the user loading animation, but it doesn't work, only when I open the next panel in v-expansion-panels with a different currency, it somehow will start and show this animation in first panel.

in template in expansion-panel module

```
<v-btn @click="getAddress(currency, i);" outlined :loading="loading[i]" v- 
if="!currency.address" text dark>Get Deposit Address</v-btn>
```

in data

```
loading: [false, false, false, false],
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You passed wrong parameter to the function. It should have been

```
<v-btn @click="getAddress(i);"
```

Answer (score 0):

VueJS cannot detect changes in your array if you’re setting/updating a value by index, as mentioned in their documentation: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays

So, use `Vue.set` or `this.$set` instead, ie:

```
this.$set(this.loader, i, true);
```